# ImageField from Django to PIL Image to send via HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library, crop

Hi I'm a newbie to Django (and I'm non-native English speaker). I'm trying to get an image (I get the id of the image using a form via POST) from the database(ImageField), crop it with PIL Image and send it via HttpResponse. It doesn't give an error but when I receive the image "piece.jpg", it is a corrupt file. If I open it using notepad I can only see:

```
    <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=46x75 at 0x3DEA790>
```

This is my code in `views.py`:

```
    from PIL import Image

    def function(request):

        if request.method == 'POST':

            id = request.POST.get('id')
            object = Document.objects.get(pk=id)

            im = Image.open(object.docfile)

            left = 10
            top = 10
            right = 100
            bottom = 100
            cropped_image = im.crop( (left, top, right, bottom) )

            response = HttpResponse(cropped_image, content_type='image/jpg')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="piece.jpg"'
            return response
```

I tried sending just "object.docfile" and it works. But if I try to send "im" (which is a PIL image), it doesnt work.

I need to send it via `HttpResponse` because I want it as a downloadable on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpResponse` expects string or an iterator. More details in docs:

[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.**init**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.__init__)

Did you try something like this?

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='image/jpg')
cropped_image.save(response, "JPEG")
return response
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to find the solution! Your code opens the image in the browser (which is ok, because I didnt say I wanted it as a download). To get a download dialog, the code is:

```
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/jpg')
    cropped_image.save(response, "JPEG")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="piece.jpg"'
    return response
```

Thanks kind sir :)